# How to change/update the custom layout of a Dialog on orientation change in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

Im trying to change the layout of a Dialog in the onConfigurationChange of the activity. 
I have created 2 layout one in regular layouts folder and other in layouts-land, i can get the layouts if the orientations of the device is in landscape or portrait and then click to show the dialog. But if I try to change the orientation when the dialog is showing the custom layout in using is not updating.

Please help me out with this. I don't wanna use a DialogFragment to do this, is there a easier way to fix it by just using regular AlertDialog.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should create two different layouts, one for portrait and another for landscape. Then call for layout on orientation change.
Search for alert dialog with own layouts.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_dialog,null);
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Info");
alert.setView(alertLayout);
AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Hi Anuj, thats exactly what im doing.. but the layout is not updating on orientation change.. It works in Portrait or in Landscape but transaction is not working.